# Can someone explain the representation-theory tag?

Tags: representation-theory, fourier-transform

I like to think of myself as pretty interested in representation theory, but I have no idea what last line of the tag description for [representation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/representation-theory) is talking about. It reads,

> Representation theory is a broad field that studies the symmetries of mathematical objects. A representation of an object is a way to "linearize" that object as a group of matrices. It's the non-commutative analog of classical Fourier transforms.

I have a couple of nits to pick about this description overall, but that's probably a topic for the meta. My question here is, how is representation theory a non-commutative analog of classical Fourier transforms? I'm not very familiar with the classical theory of Fourier transforms, and I don't normally think of them as having anything to do with representation theory or its most basic object: a homomorphism from an algebraic object to the endomorphisms of a linear object.

My understanding is that the classical Fourier transform is an isomorphism of one familiar function space into another one with a convenient basis, but I don't see how this is a representation, or how representation theory is an analog of it. Can someone explain the connection to me?

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37021/is-fourier-analysis-a-special-case-of-representation-theory-or-an-analogue

Comment: @twnly this is a goldmine! It also seems to confirm my suspicion that the tag description is poorly written—that "representation theory" is, at worst, a generalization of the classical Fourier transfrom, rather than some kind of analog. Any idea who to take this up with? Should I post a question about it on the meta? Who writes these things?

Comment: A huge part of representation theory is the study of the group algebra $\Bbb{C}[G]$ for a finite (often non abelian) group $G$, decomposing in a finite sum of irreducible $G$-modules given by the characters. Those can be interpreted as indecomposable homomporphisms $G\to GL_n(\Bbb{C})$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups

Comment: @reuns Reducing all representation theoretic questions to what characters can detect imposes strong limitations on both represented object and representing space. Not to say that looking at characters (or analogous objects)—which we can choose to view as Fourier-theoretic if we like—is ever irrelevant. But aren't they at most a piece of the puzzle when you're not representing a group (or your group isn't finite), or when the linear space isn't Hilbert (or it is, but it has positive characteristic)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $G$ be the circle, thought of as complex numbers of norm one. The Hilbert space $L^2(G)$ of complex valued functions on $G$ carries a natural unitary representation of $G$ by the rule
$$
g \cdot f(x) = f(g^{-1}x).
$$
But $G$ is compact, so representations are (Hilbert space) direct sums of irreducible representations, and $G$ is abelian, so its irreducible representations are one-dimensional -- in this case, they are in bijection with $\mathbb{Z}$, the map being $z \mapsto z^n$. Let's call this representation $\mathbb{C}(n)$.

So we have
$$
L^2(G) = \widehat{\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}} \mathbb{C}(n). 
$$

So we can write functions on $G$ as convergent sums of functions of the form $z \mapsto z^n$,  which is to say, we can write periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with period one as convergent sums of functions $x \mapsto \exp(2 \pi i n x)$, which is of course the classical Fourier series.

Similar story with $\mathbb{R}$ and the Fourier transform, except you can't hope for something as nice as breaking a function into discrete pieces because the representations of $\mathbb{R}$ are indexed by the continuous set $\mathbb{R}$ . You instead get that $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a "direct integral" of one-dimensional spaces, which really is just language for stating the Fourier inversion formula.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying the classical theory of the Fourier transform can be completely phrased into representation theoretic language, and that really does answer about half of my question. But is there more? Is something true along the lines of "most of representation theory can be phrased in Fourier-theoretic language"? Or is this an issue of a reductive tag description?

Comment: This is an issue with the tag description. Representation theory nowadays is quite deep and broad, and I believe that the vast majority of it cannot be phrased in Fourier-theoretic language.